# Server performance abysmal, should mysql have many instances running?

Tags: mysql, centos6

Mysql appears to be sucking a good chunk of memory up. Should mysql be running so many instances?

I've considered upgrading the server's memory (because it's maxed) but I'm concerned there is a problem with mysql because to me the memory usage seems high.

How can I determine if those instances of mysql should be running and do  need that much memory?

Let me know if I can provide further details, not sure how to troubleshoot.

[image: htop sorted by res]

Comment: Your MySQL is using about 211MiB out of 2GiB. There is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: So the total of all the mysql instances is 211MiB? Where the heck is all the server memory going to then...

Comment: Is this an OpenVZ container? That is probably your problem.

Comment: @payling Systems that aren't under memory pressure don't try to make free memory. It serves no purpose. (It's not like using less now lets you use more later. You can't save up memory for later.) Unless you have evidence a system is under memory pressure, there's absolutely no reason to care how much memory is being used.

Comment: Michael, it is OpenVZ. I guess that explains when I do a free -m there is no swap space setup.

Comment: David, my understanding of htop is green bars indicate used memory pages, blue is buffered, and yellow is cache. My memory bar is all green, I'm assuming that means all memory is actively used... Does that not mean my system is under pressure?

Answer (score 0):

`phpmyadmin processlist` will show you what the connection are doing. If they are mostly sleeping you need to look at your application code to work out how to close the connection earlier. If they are mostly running queries, you need to look at your slow query log and start tuning queries. If there are a lot of blocked connection then you probably need to switch your storage engine.

But reducing the number of mysql connection might have no impact on overall performance. Analysing that, never mind fixing the problem goes way beyond the scope of a question here. You might start by reading some good books on web performance ([1](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Linux-Apache-MySQL-PHP-Performance-ebook/dp/B00U7E00H2/ref=sr_1_1?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443133516&sr=1-1&keywords=Linux%20apache%20performance), [2](http://www.amazon.co.uk/High-Performance-Web-Sites-Essential-ebook/dp/B0028N4WHY/ref=asap_bc?ie=UTF8), [3](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Web-Performance-Definitive-Daniel-Austin/dp/1491945060/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1443133684&sr=1-3&keywords=Web%20performance%20optimization))